# SopCast to external video player

Tags: android, android-video-player

I want to open SopCast streams into external video player (not SopCast Player).
Is there any solution?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You have to open a stream in SopCast, but you can turn off the sound.
Then open the following Network Stream URL in e.g. VLC:

```
http://localhost:8902
```

On Mac you might simply type in Terminal:

```
/Applications/VLC.app/Contents/MacOS/VLC -vvv http://localhost:8902
```